# How to change the align of a list of icons when hover

Tags: css

I've some problem align a list of icons.

As u can see from the pic below, there is a list of icons. When hover, the current icons enlarges itself.

What I'm trying to do is, change the direction of current icon enlarging. I wish the list align as the way displayed on the right in the pic.

Here's the code:

```
HTML code:
<div class="bar">
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="..." /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="..." /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="..." /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="..." /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="..." /></a>
  </li>
</div>


CSS code:
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    height: auto
    }

.bar li a img {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px
    }

.bar li a:hover img {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bar li a img {
    float: right;
}
```

Should do the trick. Can you create a jsFiddle of your problem?

Comment: Hey @Alfo, what u suggested is correct. It runs well on my pc. Talking'bout jsFiddle, I'm sorry not familiar with it now...

Answer (score 1):

here is what you want **[demo](http://jsbin.com/ugojih/1/edit)**

You need to use `float:right` for img

```
.bar li a img {
    float: right;
}
```

and increase the width of div

```
.bar {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's it! I've tested it myself. It runs well. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

[Add](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/5PRct/):

```
.bar li a img { 
    right: -20px;
}  
.bar li a:hover img { 
    right: 0;
}
```